# Suppose that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$ exists. Prove that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx =0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C \subset[a, b]$ be a set with measure zero. Consider the function 
$f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in C$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x \in [a, b]-C$. Suppose that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$ exists. Prove that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx =0$.

I am confused with this concept of measure zero.. ANy guidance as to how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Let $\mathcal{\chi}_{A}$ denote the indicator function on $A$.
Use linearity to break the integral in two: 
$$
\int f=\int f(\chi_{[a,b]\setminus C}+\mathcal{\chi}_{C})=\int f\mathcal{\chi}_{[a,b]\setminus C}+\int f\chi_{C}=0\cdot m([a,b]\setminus C)+1\cdot\underbrace{m(C)}_{0}=0
$$
where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

**Details**: $f$ is measurable by construction. $C$ and hence $[a,b]\setminus C$ are measurable so that the indicator functions above are also measurable. Moreover, products of measurable functions are measurable.

---

**Note**: If the idea of measure is confusing, I recommend reading a thorough treatment. The standard in undergraduate courses is [Folland's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160).